# How to extract list of images using regExp in dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm working on Flutter app and I need to extract a list images from a text using regExp which looks like:

```
"property_gallery": [
            "a:10:{i:1520;s:68:\"https://www.caribidreams.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/IMG_9764.jpg\";i:1519;s:68:\"https://www.caribidreams.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/IMG_9763.jpg\";i:1532;s:68:\"https://www.caribidreams.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/IMG_9880.jpg\";i:1528;s:68:\"https://www.caribidreams.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/IMG_9876.jpg\";i:1521;s:68:\"https://www.caribidreams.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/IMG_9767.jpg\";i:1522;s:68:\"https://www.caribidreams.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/IMG_9769.jpg\";i:1525;s:68:\"https://www.caribidreams.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/IMG_9773.jpg\";i:1523;s:68:\"https://www.caribidreams.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/IMG_9770.jpg\";i:1527;s:68:\"https://www.caribidreams.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/IMG_9875.jpg\";i:1526;s:68:\"https://www.caribidreams.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/IMG_9775.jpg\";}"
        ],
```

How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/d8292d2d4b6471e13d7e07e7a4308e2d)

```
void main() {

  String str = "a:10:{i:1520;s:68:\"https://www.caribidreams.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/IMG_9764.jpg\";i:1519;s:68:\"https://www.caribidreams.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/IMG_9763.jpg\";i:1532;s:68:\"https://www.caribidreams.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/IMG_9880.jpg\";i:1528;s:68:\"https://www.caribidreams.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/IMG_9876.jpg\";i:1521;s:68:\"https://www.caribidreams.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/IMG_9767.jpg\";i:1522;s:68:\"https://www.caribidreams.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/IMG_9769.jpg\";i:1525;s:68:\"https://www.caribidreams.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/IMG_9773.jpg\";i:1523;s:68:\"https://www.caribidreams.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/IMG_9770.jpg\";i:1527;s:68:\"https://www.caribidreams.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/IMG_9875.jpg\";i:1526;s:68:\"https://www.caribidreams.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/IMG_9775.jpg\";}";

  RegExp exp = new RegExp(r"(http(s?):)([/|.|\w|\s|-])*\.(?:jpg|gif|png)");

  Iterable<Match> matches = exp.allMatches(str);

  matches.toList().forEach((item) {
    print(item[0]);
  });

}
```

Comment: how can I get longitude and latitude from this text   : "property_map_location": [
                "a:2:{s:8:\"latitude\";s:9:\"13.143044\";s:9:\"longitude\";s:10:\"-61.165210\";}"
            ] thanks

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be a JSON object. The proper way to access properties would be deserialization. Check out the Flutter docs for JSON: https://flutter.io/json/

Comment: I think there is no way I can access the properties without extracting by using regExp